# iOS UITableView; saving cell checkmarks to disk

Tags: objective-c, ios

As per suggestion on SO, I am posting my code here to be reviewed. It was said I should not be saving and reading from disk so many times when a user selects and deselects a cell in my tableView.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *list;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.list = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Alabama", @"Alaska", @"Arizona", 
    @"Arkansas", @"California", @"Colorado", @"Connecticut", @"Delaware", @"District of Columbia",
    @"Florida", @"Georgia", @"Hawaii", @"Idaho", @"Illinois", @"Indiana", @"Iowa", @"Kansas", 
    @"Kentucky", @"Louisiana", @"Maine", @"Maryland", @"Massachusetts", @"Michigan", @"Minnesota",
    @"Mississippi", @"Missouri", @"Montana", @"Nebraska", @"Nevada", @"New Hampshire", 
    @"New Jersey", @"New Mexico", @"New York", @"North Carolina", @"North Dakota", @"Ohio",     @"Oklahoma",
    @"Oregon", @"Pennsylvania", @"Rhode Island", @"South Carolina", @"South Dakota", 
    @"Tennessee", @"Texas", @"Utah", @"Vermont", @"Virginia", @"Washington", @"West Virginia", 
    @"Wisconsin", @"Wyoming", nil];
}

- (NSString *)SettingsPlist
{
    NSString *paths = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *PlistPath = [paths stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Settings.plist"];
    return PlistPath;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[self list] count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *contentForThisRow = [[self list] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }

    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[self SettingsPlist]];

    NSString *row = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row];

    if([[dict objectForKey:row]isEqualToString:@"0"])
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }

    [[cell textLabel] setText:contentForThisRow];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSMutableDictionary *plist = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[self SettingsPlist]];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *row = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row];

    if(cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        NSString *on = @"1";
        [plist setObject:on forKey:row];
        [plist writeToFile:[self SettingsPlist] atomically:YES];
    }
    else if(cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        NSString *off = @"0";
        [plist setObject:off forKey:row];
        [plist writeToFile:[self SettingsPlist] atomically:YES];
    }
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should read the settings plist once in `-viewDidLoad:` and save the contents as a dictionary to a property.

As you are doing, it is a huge performance hit as the disk will be accessed every time a cell appears on screen during scrolling.

In `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` you then should only work on that dictionary.

Further more you could introduce a singleton-like shared object, that holds the settings and can be accessed in any class.

see my [example code](https://github.com/vikingosegundo/checkmark) for how to do multiple selection and keeping track of the selected contents.

Comment: Save in the `-viewWillDisappear:` method?

Comment: yeah, that would be a good solution.

Comment: So when the user selects and deselects a cell, do I need to keep track of that row with a boolean, and then write the boolean values to the plist?

Comment: you can change the contents in the dictionary immediately. to populate the cell correctly with the checkmark, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/13676588/106435

Comment: So you're saying it's safe to write to disk when the user selects and/or deselects cells?

Comment: dont write to disk. write to the dictionary. and write that back to disk when leaving the view.

Comment: see https://github.com/vikingosegundo/checkmark . I altered for state selection . Though it doest have code to write to disk.

Comment: I got my objects to write back to the plist successfully now.